# Too much space between words in tables

Tags: tables, spacing

I wonder how I remove the wide spaces between the words in my table. See row 4, second coloumn, "Relevance to the research question". I would like only simple space between words.

```
\documentclass
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ | m{1.5em} | m{3.0cm}| m{11cm} | } % 15.5
  \hline
  \textbf{No. }& \textbf{Criteria} & \textbf{Reason for inclusion} \\ 
  \hline
  1 & Theoretical papers & Provide the theoretical assumptions to be used in the paper \\ 
  \hline
  2 & Qualitative empirical studies & capture empirical evidence for the given problem statement \\ 
  \hline
  3 & Working papers & Ensure coverage of the most current research, valuable when assessing new emerging trends and technology \\ 
  \hline
  4 & Relevance to the research question  & The studies must be directly related to the chosen industry players, how they are meeting consumer demands, digitalization and climate change, as well as theory understating the topic  \\ 
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You could typeset the column in ragged right instead of justified. Can you show a minimal working example which shows us how you created your table, which packages you used etc?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please edit your posting and provide a minimal example, beginning with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`, that gives rise to the screenshot you posted. Only that will make it possible to fully diagnose what's going on and formulate a cure.

Comment: Welcome TeX.SE Miriam :) Please, can you provide a Minimal Working Example?

Answer (score 8):

You could use ragged right text alignment for your columns:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ | c | >{\raggedright}m{3.0cm}| >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{11cm} | } % 15.5
  \hline
  \textbf{No. }& \textbf{Criteria} & \textbf{Reason for inclusion} \\ 
  \hline
  1 & Theoretical papers & Provide the theoretical assumptions to be used in the paper \\ 
  \hline
  2 & Qualitative empirical studies & capture empirical evidence for the given problem statement \\ 
  \hline
  3 & Working papers & Ensure coverage of the most current research, valuable when assessing new emerging trends and technology \\ 
  \hline
  4 & Relevance to the research question  & The studies must be directly related to the chosen industry players, how they are meeting consumer demands, digitalization and climate change, as well as theory understating the topic  \\ 
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Or you could switch to the `tabularray` package which makes the syntax a bit easier to read:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}{
  colspec={cX[halign=l,valign=m]X[halign=l,valign=m]},
  vlines,hlines,
  row{1}={font=\bfseries}
}
  No.& Criteria & Reason for inclusion\\ 
  1 & Theoretical papers & Provide the theoretical assumptions to be used in the paper \\ 
  2 & Qualitative empirical studies & capture empirical evidence for the given problem statement \\ 
  3 & Working papers & Ensure coverage of the most current research, valuable when assessing new emerging trends and technology \\ 
  4 & Relevance to the research question  & The studies must be directly related to the chosen industry players, how they are meeting consumer demands, digitalization and climate change, as well as theory understating the topic  \\ 
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

---

Unrelated to your problem, but maybe have a look at the documentation of the `booktabs` package for some inspiration about professional looking tables. Your table could be greatly improved by removing most of the lines.

I would suggest something like the following layout:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}{
  colspec={@{}cX[halign=l]X[halign=l,3]@{}},
  row{1}={font=\bfseries},
  hline{1,2,Z}={solid}
}
  No.& Criteria & Reason for inclusion\\ 
  1 & Theoretical papers & Provide the theoretical assumptions to be used in the paper \\ 
  2 & Qualitative empirical studies & capture empirical evidence for the given problem statement \\ 
  3 & Working papers & Ensure coverage of the most current research, valuable when assessing new emerging trends and technology \\ 
  4 & Relevance to the research question  & The studies must be directly related to the chosen industry players, how they are meeting consumer demands, digitalization and climate change, as well as theory understating the topic  \\ 
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I have no clue what I am doing, so dont think I have the capacity to make it look more professional hahaha

Comment: @MiriamLinneaRølland I added a 3rd code sample which I think would look much better

Comment: it is beautiful, thank you so much!!

Comment: @MiriamLinneaRølland You're welcome!

Answer (score 5):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`, it's possible to add an option `l` for the column type `m`: `m[l]{...}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix} 

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{NiceTabular}{ | m[c]{1.5em} | m[l]{3.0cm}| m[l]{11cm} | } % 15.5
  \hline
  \textbf{No. }& \textbf{Criteria} & \textbf{Reason for inclusion} \\ 
  \hline
  1 & Theoretical papers & Provide the theoretical assumptions to be used in the paper \\ 
  \hline
  2 & Qualitative empirical studies & capture empirical evidence for the given problem statement \\ 
  \hline
  3 & Working papers & Ensure coverage of the most current research, valuable when assessing new emerging trends and technology \\ 
  \hline
  4 & Relevance to the research question  & The studies must be directly related to the chosen industry players, how they are meeting consumer demands, digitalization and climate change, as well as theory understating the topic  \\ 
  \hline
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]